# embedding XSL code in <span> tag

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

So i have some style content saved in the node @style and i want to call it to form the style attribute of the `<span>` tag. it is also insufficient, so i want to append the `margin-left:700px` as part of the style attribute for the `<span>` tag. is this do-able?

by the way, i cannot edit the database which the xsl is calling as it is provided by the client

```
<span style="<xsl:copy-of select="Root/Node/MyFile/MyStyle/@style" margin-left:700px">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Root/Node/MyFile/MyCaption/Caption"/>
</span>
```

Btw, i tried the above and Altova complains that the Character `<` from `<xsl...` is grammatically unexpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes are probably screwing up the XSLT, try this:

```
<span>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:copy-of select="Root/Node/MyFile/MyStyle/@style" />
      <xsl:text> margin-left:700px</xsl:Text>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:copy-of select="Root/Node/MyFile/MyCaption/Caption"/>
</span>
```

I cant test it at the moment though...

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest like that, but you can do something similar:

Say you have a variable called 'style_var' with some CSS:

```
<xsl:variable name="style_var">color: blue;</xsl:variable>
```

And an HTML element, span:

```
<span>
   ...
</span>
```

I'm fairly certain you can do this:

```
<span>
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:value-of select="$style_var" /> 
      <xsl:text>margin-left: 100px;</xsl:Text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</span>
```

And you can probably swap out the variable selector for the node selector you were using above.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn about "Attribute Value Templates" in this case. This allows you to 'embed' the code directly in an attribute.

```
 <span style="{Root/Node/MyFile/MyStyle/@style}" margin-left:700px">
     <xsl:value-of select="Root/Node/MyFile/MyCaption/Caption"/>
 </span>
```

The curly braces { and } here indicate the Attribute Value Template (AVT) and indicate the code inside the braces should be executed to get the value.

You will need to ensure your xpath expression 'Root/Node/MyFile/MyStyle/@style' does indeed return the correct value though.